# How to use the selection from my vue component in my blade file

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-blade

I have build a vue-component  which takes a list of objects and two criteria lists as props. The select lists are passed to two select inputs in the template. When either one is changed the list is filtered using the selected criteria. How do I get access to this filtered list in my blade file?

Here is my code.

Blade file:

```
<subjecttable-select :data-subjecttable="{{$subjectslessons->toJson()}}"
                                 :data-departments="{{$departments->toJson()}}"
                                 :data-subjects="{{$subjects->toJson()}}" @input="selectedsubjects">
</subjecttable-select>
@{{selectedsubjects}}
```

Vue-component

```
<template>
<div >
<div class="row mb-2 mx-2">
    <form class="form-inline justify-content-between" >
    <div class="form-group row mb-1">
        <label class="col-auto  col-form-label text-md-left" for="department">Leerjaar</label>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <select id= "department" class="form-control form-control-sm custom-select" v-model="department" @change="select()">                
                <option v-for="department_item in dataDepartments" :value="department_item['id']">
                    {{department_item["name"]}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-auto  col-form-label text-md-leftt" for="subject">Vak</label>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <select id="subject" class="form-control form-control-sm custom-select" v-model="subject" @change="select()">               
                <option v-for="subject_item in dataSubjects" :value="subject_item['id']">
                    {{subject_item["description"]}}
                </option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>

    <button class="btn-outline-primary" @click="reset()">Reset</button>

    </form>

</div>

</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name:"subjecttable-select",
    props: {
        dataDepartments: { type: Array, required: true },
        dataSubjects:{ type: Array, required: true},
        dataSubjecttable: {type: Array, required: true },
        value:{},
      },

    data() {
        return {
            selected:this.dataSubjecttable,
            subject:"",
            department:"",
        }
    },
    methods:{
        select(){
              var item;
              console.log(this.subject);
              this.selected=[];
              for(item of this.dataSubjecttable){
                  if(//get the subbejctlessons who are in the selected department
                        (this.department==="" || item["department_id"]===this.department) &&
                     //whose subject is the selected subject
                        (this.subject===""|| item["subject_id"]===this.subject)  
                    ){

                      this.selected.push(item);
                  }
              }
              this.$emit('input',this.selected);
          },
        reset(){
            this.value = this.dataSubjecttable;
            this.subject = "";
            this.department="";
          },

    },
    created(){
        this.select();
    },
    filters: {
        dateFilter(value){
            var isDate = !isNaN(Date.parse(value));
            if (isDate ){
                var dateValue=new Date(value);
                return dateValue.toLocaleDateString();
            }
            else{
                return value;
            }
        }
      },
};
</script>
```

app.js

```
Vue.component('subjecttable-select', require('./components/SubjectSelection.vue').default);

/**
* Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
* the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
* or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
*/

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',  
});
```

As you can see I emit an input event in my component but I have trouble accessing the value in the blade file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, I think you want to do is load your **SelecttableSelect** component within another parent Vue component. This will allow you to trickle your events down to the parent component and use the data much more easily.

I have not tested this, but it's along the lines of what I would do to get started.  You would need to format the output to your needs.

**Lessons.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div>

        <!-- YOUR SELECT IS NOW DEFINED HERE, NOT IN THE BLADE FILE -->
        <!-- Select -->
        <subjecttable-select :data-subjecttable="dataSubjecttable"
                             :data-departments="dataDepartments"
                             :data-subjects="dataSubjects"
                             @input="updateResults"
        >
        </subjecttable-select>
        <!-- End Select  -->

        <!-- Department -->
        <div>
            <h1>Department</h1>
            <div v-if="results.department_id > 0">
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="(value, index) in findElementById(dataDepartments, results.department_id)">
                        {{ index }} : {{ value }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Department  -->

        <!-- Subject -->
        <div>
            <h1>Subject</h1>
            <div v-if="results.subject_id > 0">
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="(value, index) in findElementById(dataSubjects, results.subject_id)">
                        {{ index }} : {{ value }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Subject -->

    </div>
</template>

<script>

    // import your select component
    import SubjecttableSelect from './SubjecttableSelect';

    export default {
        components: {
            // register the component
            SubjecttableSelect,
        },
        props: {
            dataDepartments: { type: Array, required: true },
            dataSubjects:{ type: Array, required: true},
            dataSubjecttable: {type: Array, required: true },
        },
        name: "Lessons",
        data() {
            return {
                results: {
                    subject_id: 0,
                    department_id: 0,
                },
            }
        },
        methods: {
            updateResults(data) {
                this.results = data;
            },
            findElementById(element, id) {
                return element.find(el => el.id === id);
            }
        },
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**app.js**

```js
// register the new component
Vue.component('lessons', require('./components/Lessons.vue').default);

// subjecttable-select can now be imported within lessons

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',  
});
```

**your.blade.php** (please note the single quotes)

```php
<lessons :data-subjecttable='@json($subjectslessons)'
         :data-departments='@json($departments)'
         :data-subjects='@json($subjects)'>
</lessons>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I interpret your answer correctly you say there is no way to use the selected list directly in blade, for example in a foreach loop. I stil have to wrap my vue component in another component.

Comment: Blade is a PHP templating solution.  PHP is a server-side code.  This means all PHP processing is done before your data leaves the server.  Vue (Javascript) is a client-side code, processed on the client's (user's) machine after the server sends the page contents over.  So no, you can't run additional PHP on a page that has already been loaded.